# Help with a proof $f(n) \leq c \times g(n)$

Tags: calculus, limits

$f(n)=100n+\log n,g(n)=n+(\log n)^2, n \in N_+$. Prove that there exists a constant $c > 0$ such that $f(n) \leq c \times g(n)$.

I don't know how to prove this in a rigorous way, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just take $c=100$??? Since $100n\leq 100n$ and $\log n<100(\log n)^2$....

Comment: All right...what a stupid question I asked.Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

First, look at the leading terms of $f$ and $g$.  The leading term for $f$ is $100n$ and the leading term for $g$ is $n$.  Therefore, $c$ will need to be at least $100$.

Let $c=100$.  Then, you want to show that
$$
100n+\log n\leq 100n+100\log^2n.
$$
In other words, you must have that $\log n\leq 100\log^2n$ or that $1\leq 100\log n$.  Depending on the logarithm that you're using, this is true for $n$ sufficiently large (for most common logs, this is true for $n\geq 2$).

Comment: Well, I find that this is a silly question...thanks a lot.